# How can I properly implement #ID:hover{} in CSS with no missalignment on other HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, hover, alignment

So, I've been trying my hand on `<div>` elements for the first time, which I've had no problems with so far. But now, I want to have a div box, which has multiple `<a>` links, as `<img>`'s with the goal of having a `#Image:hover` function that serves as an animation.

Implentation went good as well, but now I've come across my problem, which I've found nothing specific about... the img element missaligns the other img's whenever I hover it. Now I want to know what I can implement so that it doesn't missalign...

I have this CSS section:

```
#Icons {
    margin: 8px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-height: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    max-height: 43px;
}

#Image {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#Image:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
}

#Media {
    margin: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    max-width: 43px;
    min-height: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    max-height: 43px;
}
```

And this HTML section:

```
<p id="HeaderTwo">Reachable under</p>
<div id="Icons">
    <a id="Media" href="#"><img id="Image" src="../img/discord.png" /></a>
    <a id="Media" href="#"><img id="Image" src="../img/gmail.png" /></a>
    <a id="Media" href="#"><img id="Image" src="../img/telegram.png" /></a>
    <a id="Media" href="#"><img id="Image" src="../img/youtube.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I tried including the folling bit to some CSS elements in hope that it kinda serves as a box limiter or sth. similiar, so that so no missalignment can/should happen.

```
min-width: 43px;
width: 43px;
max-width: 43px;
min-height: 43px;
height: 43px;
max-height: 43px;
```

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique and should not be used more than once.

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by misalign.

Comment: if you use my code snippets, you can see that the <div> "Icons" row moves down, away from the <p> sentence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To avoid elements from resizing the layout, use `transform scale`.

Now, aside from your specific question, please consider these fixes:

- Avoid the usage of ID for styling (also, IDs must be unique)
- Hover animation is to tell the user that the image is clickable, so the trigger should be on the `<a>` tag

```css
.image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform .3s;
  will-change: transform;
}

.media {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.media:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.075);
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#" class="media"><img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?1" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="media"><img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?2" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="media"><img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?3" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="media"><img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random?4" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. However, I don't understand what you mean by "the trigger should be on the <a> tag". Care to explain?

Comment: No problem. When you're animating a hover effect for a link, instead of using `img:hover {}`, you should use `a:hover img {}`. Otherwise, the image won't get animated if you hover another element inside that link. Like in this example, even if you hover the text link, the image doesn't animate: https://jsfiddle.net/xaon3dyk/3/ . This is how you would do it corretly: https://jsfiddle.net/3074qpsb/1/

Comment: I see, so it's kinda like a "extend" property of CSS. Thanks, good to know!